# 4 rangos de parámetros de búsqueda en SQL

Tags: sql

Estoy tratando con una sentenciar de busqueda en SQL

En le pasado lo que intente hacer es lo siguiente:

`[logid] between 7400000 and 7400200 OR 4414854 and 4414890`

Pero no resulto como deseaba, ya que lo que busco es que me aparezca entre dos rangos.
Actualmente estoy haciendo esto, pero ahora no logro ver mis resultados:

```
and [logid] >= 7400000
and [logid] <=7400200
and [logid] >=4414854
and [logid] <=4414890
```

Siento que el problema en si es sencillo pero me falta experiencia, alguno me podría ayudar a orientarme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parece que tu problema va por el NO uso de los paréntesis "()", intenta lo siguiente para indicar mejor tus condiciones:

```
([logid] >= 7400000 and [logid] <=7400200) or ([logid] >=4414854 and [logid] <=4414890)
```

Con un between sería algo así (muy parecido a lo que ya hiciste):

```
([logid] between 7400000 and 7400200) OR ([logid] between 4414854 and 4414890)
```

Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Primero que nada, gracias por el apoyo. Ya implemente lo que me dices y SI tiene logica, lo corri y aun no me arroja resultado (sigue corriendo el ejecutor). A lo cual me surgió una duda por la sentencia 'OR', en esta situación me dara solo un resultado de rangos o me dara ambos resultados? Lo menciono porque realmente busco que me de ambos resultados de rangos

Comment: De nada, es un gusto poderte ayudar. Y respecto a tu pregunta de como funciona esta condición la respuesta es que, cualquier valor que se encuentre entre 7400000 y 7400200 o 4414854 y 4414890, será mostrado como resultado. El "OR" es la clave, ya que si en vez de usarlo usas "AND" jamás te devolverá un valor, por que no existe tal posibilidad.